# Android input boxes on the next line

Tags: android-layout

Okay, so I decided to take the Google classes for learning droid devving.  I decided instead of the simple input box and button I would make multiple ones, and have each display a set color.  The issue is it is jamming all input boxes on one line, rather than their own separate  lines.  This is what I have in the activity_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message_blue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message_blue" />


<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send_blue" 
    android:onClick="sendMessageBlue" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message_orange"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message_orange" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_send_orange" 
    android:onClick="sendMessageOrange" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the main java class

```
package com.example.color.texts;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ColorTexts extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.colortexts.MESSAGE";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_texts);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_color_texts, menu);
    return true;
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button for Blue */
public void sendMessageBlue(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message_blue);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button for Red */
public void sendMessageRed(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivityRed.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message_red);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}


/** Called when the user clicks the Send button for Orange */
public void sendMessageOrange(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivityOrange.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message_orange);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Now I guess the question is how to either tell it to start a new line, like android:layout_next="1" or something (I KNOW THAT DOESN'T EXIST), or would I have to add to the public class? Such as make another layout file and reference to that?  I highly doubt the latter would work.

EDIT:  Per the instructions laid out, I think this is how I was supposed to do it, but it only know shows the first line :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message_blue"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message_blue" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send_blue" 
    android:onClick="sendMessageBlue" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message_red"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:hint="@string/edit_message_red" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_send_red" 
    android:onClick="sendMessageRed" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message_orange"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message_orange" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_send_orange" 
    android:onClick="sendMessageOrange" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent layout is set to be `android:orientation="horizontal"`. This needs to be set to `android:orientation="vertical"`.

**EDIT:** Here is the reference in the Android docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation

Comment: When I change that none of the input boxes show up, just the send button, but the orientation of the buttons is correct :D

Comment: Edit:  I don't the fact that the buttons are now underneath the input boxes.  I got rid of weight="1" as I don't believe it applies to vertical, and like the results of match_parent for width, but I don't like the buttons underneath.  Surely there is a way to make horizontal with one input box and button on one line, and the next input box and button on the next.

Comment: Absolutely. You can nest LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation within the main LinearLayout. So for each EditText/Button combination you can have them horizontally laid out, and each of the child LinearLayout's will be laid out vertically.

Alternatively you might consider using a TableLayout and put each EditText/Button inside of a TableRow.

Comment: On each of the children LinearLayout elements change the height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: DOH!!  I feel like an dunderhead now lol, what a simple mistake that was. TY TY TY it works as intended.  Much love to you and this wonderful site :D